# Condition for JOIN query needs to be corrected

Tags: c#, sql, database, sql-server-2005, join

My table structure is as follows:

```
TradeNo | OrderNo | Buy_Sell | Trade_Qty | Market_Rate | Sauda_Date    | Expiry_Date

 1001      2001      Buy        100          5000       28 Feb 2013         2013-03-29 

 1002      2002      Buy        500          8000       28 Feb 2013         2013-03-29 

 1001      2001      Sell       70           5600       1 Mar 2013          2013-03-29
```

for each row TradeNo and OrderNo are unique combination.

I wanted to select all those records having unique TradeNo and OrderNo combination [Like 1st and 3rd] , where Sauda_Date may be different but within Expirydate and according to buy/sell.

From this example following rows should get selected:

```
TradeNo | OrderNo | Buy_Sell | Trade_Qty | Market_Rate | Sauda_Date    | Expiry_Date

     1001      2001      Buy        100          5000       28 Feb 2013         2013-03-29 


     1001      2001      Sell       70           5600       1 Mar 2013          2013-03-29
```

These rows are selected becase Tradeno and OrderNo is unique for these and according to buy sell and sauda date is within expiry date.

I have tried following query but it did not work:

```
select
    t1.TradeNo,
    t1.OrderNo,
    t1.Trade_Qty,
    t1.Market_Rate,
    t1.Sauda_Date,
    t1.Expirydate
from 
    tradeFile t1,
    tradeFile t2 
where 
    t1.TradeNo=t2.TradeNo and
    t1.OrderNo=t2.OrderNo
```

Please help me.

Comment: Of TradeNo and OrderNo are unique combination, there won't be 2 records with the same combination!

Comment: yes there are two records with same combination in my db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT  t1.*
FROM tradeFile t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT TradeNo, OrderNO
    FROM tradeFile
    GROUP BY TradeNo, OrderNO
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
) AS t2  ON t1.TradeNo = t2.TradeNo
        AND t1.OrderNo = t2.OrderNO;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a38d1/1)

Comment: when i put expiry date condition its not working>>t1.Sauda_Date<t2.Expiry_Date

Comment: @Freelancer -  You can put it in the subquery or in the outer query. [**Like this**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a38d1/5)